# Why is the commit message inside parentheses wrapped so strangely?

Tags: indentation, git, line-breaks

I sometimes need to do some remarks in parentheses in my commit message's detailed part. But when the parenthesized text comes to the rightmost column and is line-broken, the next line for some reason begins from the column after the opening parenthesis. See the screenshot below.

[image: screenshot]

So, what's going on here? Why does it happen, and how can I make wrapping continue from the first column?

Comment: Can you check the output of `set lisp?`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble no output, the command simply remains there after I press Enter (as with other `set XXX` commands).

Comment: @Ruslan When you add a question mark to the end of a :set command it queries the current value of the option.

Comment: Yes, the question mark should have been part of the command

Comment: @D.BenKnoble sorry, mistook the `?` for ending of you question :) The output is `nolisp`.

Comment: What is the output of `set cindent?` and `set cinoptions?` ? I could reproduce it with `cindent` set and `cinoptions` containing `(N`.

Comment: @Ralf `cindent` is enabled, and `cinoptions=N-s,g0,:0,(0`.

Comment: You have this set in your vimrc? `verbose set cindent?` and `verbose set cinoptions?` will tell you where this options where last set.

Comment: @Ralf yes. Apparently, I should have applied `set cino` only to `.c` and `.cpp` files, while currently they are unconditional...

Comment: No, `cino` is not the problem, it's `cindent`. The option `cino` has no effect, when `cindent` is not set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in your comment you have `cindent` and `cinoptions` set like:

```
set cindent
set cinoptions=N-s,g0,:0,(0
```

The options `cindent` should only be set for the file types you want to use it. It is set automatically for the C or CPP file types (assuming you have `filetype indent on` in your vimrc [or better: `filetype plugin indent on`]).

Remove the line `set cindent` from your vimrc.

---

BTW: If you want to change filetype specific settings I recommend to work with a file in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin` (e.g. `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim` to change settings for the C filetype). See `:help ftplugin-overrule`, especially point 3.